# disable ctrl-escape

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a Windows 7 user that spends 80% of my time in gvim, with caps remapped to escape.

Just recently I have started hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>escape</kbd> (well, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Caps</kbd>) by mistake, which pops up the start menu. This then requires and awkward escape > <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> > <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> combo to get back to gvim.

Is there a way to disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the answer to [How can I disable selected Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/61069/disable-windows-7-shortcuts) might apply.  Try following those instructions, but changing them to apply to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: ^Escape::return 

worked a treat,

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I recommend the program "hotkeynet" for similar situations. Lets you remap and assign logic/key combos to a single keypress etc.