# Is there a way to disable Windows shortcuts without installing third party software?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Specifically, I want to disable the Alt + Space shortcut because on my new Dell keyboard I find that I am frequently hitting this key combination by accident.

I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/61069/how-can-i-disable-selected-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts) answer, but I am hoping we can do better. It seems ridiculous to me that one should have to install third party software in order to disable a keyboard shortcut. Surely there must be a may to do this somewhere in the Windows settings or with a registry key.

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions because you don't find the answers satisfactory; instead place a bounty on the existing question requesting additional/newer/different answers.

Comment: "Surely there must be a may to do this somewhere in the Windows settings or with a registry key." - There are hundreds of things you can do in Windows that is only possible because of third-party software.  It might be rediculous, but that does not the fact, third-party software is still required.

Comment: The question is NOT an exact duplicate of the other question. Draw a Venn diagram if you are in doubt about this.